# If condition not working inside dynamic sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamicquery

In below dynamic sql I am trying to check whether temporary table (#Table) already exists if not then create using some other table.

But my problem is that irrespective what is the value in IF condtion, I am always getting error for select statement which is inside If condition

> There is already an object named '#Table' in the database.

Below is the sql code.

```
declare @sqlstring varchar(max)

set @sqlstring=N'

select * into #Table from mst_country


if(object_id(''tempdb..#Table'') is null)
begin

    select * into #Table from mst_country_bkp

end'

exec(@sqlstring)
```

Can any one please let us know why it can be happening?

Comment: Why are you doing that in dynamc SQL anyway?

Comment: Actually my original query is much complex and bigger..It is just a small snippet to show what is the exact problem.. If you replace mst_country whith any of your database table it will give you error..so basically to simplify question I have used this query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When compiling the sqlserver doesn't allow you creating the same temporary table in the same scope twice. You can actually cheat the sqlserver like this, so it doesn't realize that the temporary table was already created:

```
declare @sqlstring varchar(max)

set @sqlstring=N'

exec(''select * into #Table from mst_country'')


if(object_id(''tempdb..#Table'') is null)
    select * into #Table from mst_country_bkp
'

exec(@sqlstring)
```

Comment: It worked perfectly fine..Thanks..But one query..You are saying " sqlserver doesn't allow you creating the same temporary table in the same scope twice" but I have used IF condition..so you want to say..sql server will not consider if statement?

Comment: That is correct. You are attempting to create the same table again. Even though you have an condition. SQL server doesn't evaluate your condition, the error occurs at compile time, not the execution itself

Answer (score 3):

You need to drop the temp table once you are done with your query like this:

```
declare @sqlstring varchar(max)

set @sqlstring=N'
IF OBJECT_ID(''tempdb.dbo.#Table'', ''U'') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #Table;  

select * into #Table from mst_country


if(object_id(''tempdb..#Table'') is null)
begin  
    select * into #Table from mst_country_bkp    
end'

exec(@sqlstring)
```

**EDIT:**

The issue is that you cannot have two SELECT INTO inside the same sql statement. [This is a leftover from SQL 6.5 which did not have deferred name resolution.](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/8c7ddea5-1021-429c-bdb2-c3a4df245320/why-am-i-getting-there-is-already-an-object-named-temptable-in-the-database-within-my-sql?forum=transactsql) Try this:

```
declare @sqlstring varchar(max)

set @sqlstring=N'
IF OBJECT_ID(''tempdb.dbo.#Table'', ''U'') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #Table;  

select * into #Table from mst_country

insert into #Table(col1,col2,....)
select col1,col2,.... from mst_country_bkp    
end'

exec(@sqlstring)
```

Comment: @Rahul..I do not think it will help..Everything depends on first statement of this query.

Comment: @SagarShirke:- The error which you have reported in your question is saying the same thing. Did you try to execute the above query?

Comment: @SagarShirke The issue is that the table already exists so it's not the `if` causing the error, it's the first `select into`

Comment: @DavidG..@Rahul... for better clarity I am modifying my question little

Comment: Perhaps put an `if exists...drop table` at the start.

Comment: @DavidG..This problem error is comming for statement which is inside If statement..But ideally it should get executed if #Table exists..since I am checking this condition in If clause..

Comment: @SagarShirke At least try the code given to you before dismissing it so quickly.

Comment: @SagarShirke:- I have updated my code to handle the table exists error. Try to check that.

Comment: @DavidG..I have tried  both the codes posted by Rahul.. may be I am too quick.. :)

Comment: @SagarShirke:- What are you trying to achieve? Just check the link which I have just updated.

Comment: @RahulTripathi..I am checking the link posted by you..actually I want to do one simple thing.. that check one particular temporary table exists or not if not then create that Table with same name but by using different table.

Comment: @SagarShirke:- Updated my answer. Please check that. You cannot use the `select into` 2 times in your sql statement and which is why you were getting the error. You need to use the `insert into` clause to insert the records into the temp table.

Comment: With your last modification, you risk having data from both tables in the temporary table

Comment: @t-clausen.dk:- I think that is what OP is looking for, ie, OP wants the data from both the tables into the temp table.

Comment: @RahulTripathi...Thanks,  your link has helped me to understand what is the problem..I appreciate your time and efforts for helping me..

Comment: Very Good @RahulTripathi +1.   Nice article you found